# Ошибка error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Tags: python, opencv

```
while(True):

    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)


    red1 = np.array([170, 70, 50], np.uint8)
    red2 = np.array([180,255,255], np.uint8)


    red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, red1, red2)

    kernel = np.ones((7, 7), "uint8")

    red_mask = cv2.dilate(red_mask, kernel)

    res_red = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask = red_mask)

    cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(red_mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for pic, c in enumerate(cnts):
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        print(area)
        if (700 > area > 350):
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            image = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y),
                                  (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, "Red detected", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, (0, 0, 255))
```

Как я могу исправить эту ошибку? раньше все работало 0-0

Comment: Судя по картинке ваш код вообще не чего не делает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправление строки `cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:/Users/Master/Desktop/New/forowner/Video.asf')` помогло.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).